# Fixar coluna de uma tabela HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma tabela consideravelmente longa e para melhor experiência do usuário, quero colocar a primeira coluna, que apresentará imagens, como fixa, tipo no excel, congelar o painel para que a visualização fique melhor no mobile.

Estou utilizando Bootstrap na construção da tabela e procurei aqui no fórum possíveis alternativas ao meu caso, e usei como base o seguinte [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/) que é exatamente como eu quero que fique.

Mas não consegui adaptar ao meu, as imagens ficam flutuando e não estão enquadradas na célula da tabela, poderiam me ajudar?

Segue meu fiddle: https://jsbin.com/wubeguhodi/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score -1):

Coloque suas imagens dentro de uma tag de imagem.

```
<img class='exmp'>
```

No css

```
.exmp{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: as imagens ja estão dentro de uma tag de imagem @Bruno Costa

Comment: Acredito que você não disponibilizou o fiddle correto.

Comment: como assim? estão dentro do `th`

Comment: Amigo dentro de cada 'th' você insere uma tag 'img' e manipula dentro do css, exatamente como está ali em cima

Answer (score -1):

A forma mais facil de você congelar a primeira coluna da tabela usando `Bootstrap`, é adicionar o `datatables` à sua pagina e inicie a sua tabela com `fixedColumn = true`.

```js
var source = document.getElementById("tmplPessoa").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var tabela = document.querySelector("#pessoas tbody");

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  faker.locale = "pt_BR";
  var nome = {};
  nome.Primeiro = faker.name.firstName();
  nome.Ultimo = faker.name.lastName();
  var nascimento = faker.date.past(50, new Date(1992, 08, 20));
  
  var pessoa = {};
  pessoa.Avatar = faker.internet.avatar();
  pessoa.Nascimento = nascimento.toLocaleDateString();
  pessoa.Nome = faker.name.findName(nome.Primeiro, nome.Ultimo);
  pessoa.Endereco = faker.address.streetAddress();
  pessoa.Cidade = faker.address.city();
  pessoa.Estado = faker.address.stateAbbr();
  pessoa.CEP = faker.address.zipCode();
  pessoa.Pais = faker.locales[faker.locale].address.default_country;
  pessoa.Telefone = faker.phone.phoneNumber();
  pessoa.Email = faker.internet.email(nome.Primeiro, nome.Ultimo);
  
  var html = template(pessoa);
  var wrapper = document.createElement("table");
  wrapper.innerHTML = html;
  tabela.appendChild(wrapper.rows[0]);
}

$('#pessoas').DataTable({
    fixedColumns: true
});
```

```css
th, td { white-space: nowrap; }
div.pessoas_wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Faker/3.1.0/faker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Faker/3.1.0/locales/pt_BR/faker.pt_BR.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

<table id="pessoas" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive nowrap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Avatar</th>
      <th>Nascimento</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Endereco</th>
      <th>Cidade</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>CEP</th>
      <th>Pais</th>
      <th>Telefone</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
  </tbody>
</table>

<script id="tmplPessoa" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="{{Avatar}}" /></td>
    <td>{{Nascimento}}</td>
    <td>{{Nome}}</td>
    <td>{{Endereco}}</td>
    <td>{{Cidade}}</td>
    <td>{{Estado}}</td>
    <td>{{CEP}}</td>
    <td>{{Pais}}</td>
    <td>{{Telefone}}</td>
    <td>{{Email}}</td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: Tobias, obrigado pela resposta, porém não consegui entender a partir do exemplo que voce colocou, necessito deste framework?